# How do I turn an IObservable<IObservable<T>> into an IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I have a stream for the state of the left mouse button:

```
var leftMouseButton = mouse.Select(x => x.LeftButton).DistinctUntilChanged();
```

I then `Window` this to give me an *observable of observables* representing drags of the mouse:

```
var leftMouseDrag = mouse
    .Select(mouseState => new Point(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y))
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Window(leftMouseButton.Where(x => x == ButtonState.Pressed), x => leftMouseButton.Where(y => y != x));
```

Now I would like to make a stream off of `leftMouseDrag` that gives lists of points. Every time the user completes a drag (LMB down -> move -> LMB up) it should fire with the list of positions that the mouse moved through.

How do I take an `IObservable<IObservable<Point>>` and turn it into an `IObservable<IEnumerable<Point>>`?

Comment: Could you not use Drag and Drop, and pull the coordinates from the `BeginDrag` and `EndDrag` eventArgs?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane I am using the mouse API from MonoGame.

Comment: Ah fair enough. My bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Window` operator to `Buffer` operator ([this overload).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229621(v=vs.103).aspx)

The operator produces `IObservable<IList<T>>` , in which `IList` is of `IEnumerable`

---

Alternative solution based on OP comment:

```
var leftMouseDragLists = leftMouseDrag.SelectMany(i => i.ToList());
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention in my question that I am using `leftMouseDrag` elsewhere so I would like to keep it unchanged.